# Hmac with openssl's command line tool with a key that might contain null bytes

Tags: bash, quoting, openssl, escape-characters

Let's say I want to do an SHA256HMAC digest of a file with the `openssl` command line utility:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$(cat $KEY_FILE)" -hex "$TARGET_FILE"
```

How can I protect this command against the `$(cat $KEY_FILE)` generating null bytes (or other potentially troublesome characters) if those happen to exist in `$KEY_FILE`?

Comment: You can't provide arbitrary binary input as arguments because strings can't contain null bytes (which suggests that the utility *is not* designed to take that). Quotes are not a problem though. Do you have an applied example of where you're seeing an issue?

Comment: @MichaelHomer This is the only utility I've ever seen that is supposed to take arbitrary binary as a command line argument, so I don't have any other examples.

Comment: It [appears that `-mac HMAC -macopt hexkey:1f0cda` is supported](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/dgst.html). If you don't have any null bytes and the file doesn't end with linebreaks then your version is fine, though.